# unknown filesystem grub rescue ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub

I have linux under windows partition. I have 4 disks in which one of them windows is installed and 2 for data. Another one is 15GB hard drive, Which always asks me to format either I open it in windows or in ubuntu. Due to some reason I need to format that 15GB partition which always asks me to format. After that when I open my ubuntu system, it shows me a error

```
 unknown filesystem
 grub rescue
```

I write

```
grub rescue>ls
```

then couple of file system appear, so I try to configure grub by

```
ls (hd0,gpt0)/
```

and other partition. But it always says 'Unknown file system'. I tried everything but fails.

I download ubuntu image file to create ubuntu live USB and try to install grub by trying ubuntu option. But again when I run my ubuntu OS, again same error appears.

At this point, I think I can't  recover my OS. So I move to backup my ubuntu OS data. I download Internals Linux Reader and tried to back up data. I can see there is linux partition which name is 'Linux Swap Volume'. But when I try to open that partition it always shows 'Can't Open Disk'.

I am stuck now. I have my 2 year of work in ubuntu OS. Please please tell me how I can recover my data or run my Ubuntu OS normally.

Comment: Are you telling us that you do not have a backup?

Comment: Sorry, But yes, You are right. I don't have backup..

Comment: when you run a live CD you can simply mount the disk; no need to mess with grub there. (and then simply copy /backup the files first). (btw, the Swap volume is not what you're looking for, just ignore for now)

Comment: If this is an urgent problem you would get a much faster response if you posted in an appropriate site.  StackOverflow is for programming/software development questions, and this clearly is None of the Above.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you may have formatted your boot partition, rendering your Ubuntu system unbootable.

I suggest booting into windows and seeing if you can grab your data off the Ubuntu disk using a tool such as Linux Reader http://www.diskinternals.com/linux-reader/

Comment: live cd is probably easier.

Comment: @Sirex Downloading a ~1GB ISO, finding a CD, burning it, restarting your computer and booting into the CD is easier than installing a small windows program to browse files on Linux partition?

Comment: there's plenty of linux live distros that'll fit into a fraction of that and boot right off a usb stick. I'm also assuming they installed linux from one in the first place, given that most distros are installed from such these days. Also no information in the original question that windows even still boots - given that grub is borked.